# A question on self adjoint operator and numerical range.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $T$ be self-adjoint operator. Prove that 
$$
\Vert T\Vert = \sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda \in W(T)\}
$$
We are supposed to use the [following exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165081/numerical-range-of-an-operator-on-hilbert-spaces) and the fact that $r(T) = \Vert T\Vert$. How does this function?

Comment: What is your definition of $r(T)$?

Comment: The spectral radius of T.

Comment: And how do you define it?

Comment: What is $W(T)$?

Comment: The link to the exercise shows the definition of W(T).

Comment: W(T):={(Tx;x)∣x∈H, ∥x∥=1}.

Comment: r(T) = sup{ |λ|: λ in spectrum(T)}

Comment: I suggest you add these definitions to the original question, for the convenience of readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For all $\lambda\in W(T)$ we have $\lambda=(Tx,x)$ for some $x\in H$ with $\Vert x\Vert=1$. Hence 
$$
|\lambda|=|(Tx,x)|\leq\Vert Tx\Vert\Vert x\Vert=\Vert Tx\Vert\leq\Vert T\Vert\Vert x\Vert=\Vert T\Vert
$$
This implies 
$$
\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in W(T)\}\leq\Vert T\Vert\tag{1}
$$

2) From exercise you mentioned above it follows that $\sigma(T)\subset\overline{W(T)}$.

3) For all subsets $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ we have $\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in A\}=\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in \overline{A}\}$.

4) From paragraphs 2 and 3 we conclude
$$
\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in W(T)\}=\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in \overline{W(T)}\}\geq\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in \sigma(T)\}=r(T)=\Vert T\Vert \tag{2}
$$

5) The result follows from inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$