# Is it true that $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle x, Tx\rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ be a bounded linear operator on this space. In a calculation a book I was reading, it seems to be implied that:
$$\|T\| = \sup_{\substack{\|x\|=1 \\ x \neq 0}}\langle x, Tx\rangle,$$
but I did not find this characterization of the norm anywhere else. Is this true? By Cauchy-Schwarz it is clearly true that:
$$\|T\| \le \sup_{\substack{\|x\|=1 \\ x \neq 0}}\langle x, Tx\rangle$$
holds, but the reverse inequality I don't know.

Comment: Is $T$ also self-adjoint? Then your desired equality is true, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166088/a-question-on-self-adjoint-operator-and-numerical-range?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: In general, this isn't true.  Just consider rotations in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for instance.

Comment: Ahh, okay! I think an additional hypothesis of self-adjointness is necessary indeed! Thanks!

Comment: Try a real Hilbert space (e.g., $\Bbb R^2$) and an anti-self-adjoint $T$  (e.g., a skew-symmetric matrix).

Comment: Did you get the inequality reversed in your "it is clearly true that"?  The reverse inequality in fact is true, and the proof is by Cauchy-Schwarz.  It's the inequality you have shown and labelled incorrectly as true which may fail.  .... Additionally, this may be minor, but you need absolute values around the inner products in order for it to be true in the self-adjoint case (as a trivial example, $Tx = -x$)

Comment: It seems like it should also be true if $T$ is normal.

Comment: @InMathweTrust For an example over a complex inner product space, consider the transformation $T:\Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2$ given by $T(x_1,x_2) = (x_2,0)$. Verify that $\|T\| = 1$, but the maximum possible value of $\langle x, Tx \rangle$ is $1/2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Only if $H$ is a complex (as opposed to real) inner product space. See Brian's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily true. Consider next example: let $H = \mathbb{R}^2$ with the dot product and $T(x_1, x_2) = (-x_2, x_1)$, then $\langle x, Tx\rangle = (x_1, x_2) \cdot (-x_2, x_1) = 0 \;\forall (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Obviously $T$ is bounded operator with norm $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|x\|=1$ (since $\|Tx\|=\|x\|$).

However it is true that $\|T\| = \sup_{\substack{\|x\|=1, \|y\|=1}}\langle y, Tx\rangle$. This is obvious when $T \equiv 0$, overwise, we can find $x$, such that $\|x\|=1$ and $Tx \neq 0$. Take for them $y := \frac{Tx}{\|Tx\|}$, then $\|y\|=1$, therefore $$\sup_{\|y\|=\|x\|=1}\langle y, Tx\rangle = \sup_{\|y\|=\|x\|=1, Tx \neq 0}\langle y, Tx\rangle \geq \sup_{\|x\|=1, Tx \neq 0} \frac{\langle Tx, Tx\rangle}{\|Tx\|} = \sup_{\|x\|=1, Tx \neq 0} \|Tx\| = \|T\|$$

From the Cauchy inequality we know that $|\langle y, Tx\rangle| \leq \|y\| \cdot \|Tx\|$, therefore $\sup_{\substack{\|x\|=\|y\|=1}}\langle y, Tx\rangle \leq \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\| = \|T\|$.